# drive is not accessible chkdsk raw

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery, format, chkdsk

So I have this D drive on my Dell laptop having important information, and it said first it's not accessible, then I did the chkdsk D: /f /r and it said the drive is RAW, thus no chkdsk, what the best way to go around this and get access?

Comment: It appears the drive has a hardware error. Try some of the common recovery tools to see if they work

Comment: Like what, becauae there are many recovery tools

Comment: Yes sure, the duplicate touches data recovery from logical file system issue, but it seems stretch every logical data recovery issue is answered by that. Added to the duplicate answer isn't that great. *I am going to vote reopen* this is a ridiculous 'closed because duplicate'. There's better reasons to close this, for example lack of details, but those can be asked for.

Comment: There are a LOT of questions here on recovering data from damaged drives, some marked as duplicates of others, but many with good answers. I recommend going through those. Here's a simple search to start you out: https://superuser.com/search?q=recover+data